# How important is healthcare reform/plan to Democratic voters?

Tags: united-states, healthcare, public-opinion, democratic-party

All four leading Democratic candidates have spelled out, in more or less detail, their vision for a healthcare reform/plan. But how important is the issue to Democratic voters, i.e. are there any polls on how much importance Democratic voters attach to healthcare and/or its reform?

To make the question perhaps more interesting: are there any demographics or socioeconomic factors that alter this perception?

Answer (score 5):

There's this [pretty solid looking poll](https://www.kff.org/health-reform/poll-finding/kff-health-tracking-poll-june-2019/) from June that shows Health care is the most important topic democrats (and democrat-leaning independents) want to talk about, or at least hear about in the debates.

Unfortunately it doesn't have a demographic or geographic breakdown, which would have been nice, but it should at least give you some insight into the core of your question.

[image]

Comment: More specifically, they apparently consider it the *most important topic* ***in federal debates***.  That's not the same as most important topic overall: perhaps on other topics they consider important all Democratic candidates agree and there is nothing to debate, or perhaps other topics they consider important aren't decided federally.

Comment: @gerrit That is an excellent point, thank you. Made a small edit to reflect that distinction.